# Any way to send an email (v2) with blank "to" field in Power Automate?

Tags: email, power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that pulls some variables from Excel and then sends an email for each row in the file, using the "Send an Email (V2)" connector. For confidentiality I only put the recipients' addresses into the BCC field (so none of them can see anyone else's contact info); I just populate an array with the recipients' email addresses (if not null), join them with semi-colons, and push the output of the join into the BCC field.

Collecting the emails, using the join, and sending to them as BCC recipients all works just fine. The problem is, we have a license limitation of 10K emails sent per day, and so using the "to" field to send to a no-reply service account for every single message cuts the number of messages I can send by about 1/3, with absolutely no value other than avoiding error messages.

Is there any workaround that would only actually send to the BCC recipients and would ignore the "to" recipient so I can use my quota more efficiently?

Comment: You could try using the Microsoft Graph API but that'd take you a bit work and I suspect it will still want  a TO field to be populated.  The connector for Outlook is clearly mandatory, the red star gives that away.  I checked the SendGrid options and the TO field is also mandatory.  Not sure if SendGrid accepts a blank string or something though.  That's my two cents.

Comment: Thanks, Skin - I was afraid of that, but thought I'd check just in case.